# Com trocar dados entre um mobile(android) e outro dispositivo através da comunicação Bluetooth?

Tags: android, conexão, mobile

Como posso me conectar e desconectar com um dispositivo qualquer por meio da comunicação Bluetooth e depois trocar(enviar e/ou receber) dados?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quer um exemplo grande, e funcional, pode olhar essa [minha aplicação no GitHub, SerialBTControl](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl).

A [ActivityMain](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/ActivityMain.java) inicia a [ActivityDeviceList](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/ActivityDeviceList.java) na linha 159, para listar os dispositivos Bluetooth existentes/que podem ser pareados.

Essa [ActivityDeviceList](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/ActivityDeviceList.java) só serve para listar os dispositivos, e devolver para a [ActivityMain](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/ActivityMain.java), qual foi o dispositivo selecionado pelo usuário. Dê uma olhada no método `onCreate`, linha 66, especialmente o `BroadcastReceiver`, que é o responsável por receber do Android os dispositivos, e encaminhá-los a um `ListView`.

O método `onItemClick`, na linha 175, é quem termina a [ActivityDeviceList](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/ActivityDeviceList.java), devolvendo o dispositivo selecionado para a [ActivityMain](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/ActivityMain.java), que trata esse término no método `activityFinished`, na linha 133. Em `activityFinished`, na linha 141, cria-se o objeto responsável pela comunicação em si, que é um objeto da classe [BTCommunicator](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/BTCommunicator.java).

A classe [BTCommunicator](https://github.com/BandTec/SerialBTControl/blob/master/src/br/com/bandtec/serialbtcontrol/BTCommunicator.java), por sua vez, é a responsável por encaminhar as mensagens para o outro dispositivo, utilizando um `OutputStream` comum do Java, como mostra o método `sendMessage`, na linha 246.

Para receber dados do outro dispositivo, deveria-se utilizar um `InputStream` a partir de outra `Thread`, como mostra o comentário na linha 139, que invoca o método `receiveMessage`, também comentado na linha 261.

Esse aplicativo funciona bem, e foi bastante testado. Inclusive, está no [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.bandtec.serialbtcontrol).

Esse meu app, por sua vez, é baseado em outro projeto open-source, chamado [LEGO-MINDSTORMS-MINDdroid](https://github.com/NXT/LEGO-MINDSTORMS-MINDdroid), que também pode te servir como referência, assim como me serviu.

Comment: vlw cara.. ainda vou dar uma olhada nesse seu código provavelmente é o que eu estava procurando... vou dar +1 no seu post e até amanha estarei dando os pontos a você.

Comment: @PedroRangel Sem problemas! Qualquer coisa, é só perguntar! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nunca usei em android, porém, a comunicação bluetooth não é muito diferente de um socket de rede, basicamente você estabelece um canal entre os dois dispositivos e envia/recebe dados por esse canal. Se você mesmo vai implementar os dois pontos da comunicação é relativamente fácil, porém, se for para se comunicar com um dispositivo específico vai ser preciso saber qual protocolo esse dispositivo implementa.

A própria documentação do android me parece um bom ponto de partida, ela inclui alguns exemplos funcionais sobre como identificar e conectar a um dispositivo.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: eu já tinha dado uma olhada.. na documentação falta algumas coisas q eles não explicam com clareza passando por cima de algumas coisas importantes.. queria realmente um codigo completo e funcional..

Answer (score 1):

Não testei, mas parece me um bom código de ajuda:
[[Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369585/how-to-connect-with-paired-bluetooth-device-programmatic-in-android?lq=1)

Codigo:

```
    package com.bluetooth;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import android.R.bool;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class BluetoothDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ListView listViewDetected;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    Button buttonSearch,buttonOn,buttonDesc,buttonOff;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,detectedAdapter;
    static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    BluetoothClass bdClass;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    private ButtonClicked clicked;
    ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
        listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
        buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff); 
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        clicked = new ButtonClicked();
        handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        /*
         * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth devices;
         * this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
         */
        listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();
        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
        listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickedonPaired);
    }
    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();            
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    class ListItemClicked implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            Log.i("Log", "The dvice : "+bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we can directly call the
             * connect(). but for the safer side we must usethe threading object.
             */
            //callThread();
            //connect(bdDevice);
            Boolean isBonded = false;
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                if(isBonded)
                {
                    //arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getPairedDevices();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }//connect(bdDevice);
            Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
        }       
    }
    class ListItemClickedonPaired implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            bdDevice = arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            try {
                Boolean removeBonding = removeBond(bdDevice);
                if(removeBonding)
                {
                    arrayListpaired.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                Log.i("Log", "Removed"+removeBonding);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /*private void callThread() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Boolean isBonded = false;
                try {
                    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                    if(isBonded)
                    {
                        arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }//connect(bdDevice);
                Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
            }           
        }.start();
    }*/
    private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) { 
        Boolean bool = false;
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
            Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Class[] par = {};
            Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
            Object[] args = {};
            bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);// this invoke creates the detected devices paired.
            //Log.i("Log", "This is: "+bool.booleanValue());
            //Log.i("Log", "devicesss: "+bdDevice.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bool.booleanValue();
    };


    public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    {  
        Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }  


    class ButtonClicked implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOn:
                onBluetooth();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                startSearching();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDesc:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonOff:
                offBluetooth();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                try
                {
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(arrayListBluetoothDevices.size()<1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                    detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean flag = true;    // flag to indicate that particular device is already in the arlist or not
                    for(int i = 0; i<arrayListBluetoothDevices.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(device.getAddress().equals(arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress()))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag == true)
                    {
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    };
    private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        BluetoothDemo.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
    private void onBluetooth() {
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");
        }
    }
    private void offBluetooth() {
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }
    private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }
    class HandleSeacrh extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 111:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E no mail main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonOn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make Discoverable"/>
   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Search"/>
   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/buttonOff"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Bluetooth Off"/>

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listViewPaired"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="120dp">

   </ListView>

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listViewDetected"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adicionar esta permissão no "menifest file":

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Outros links que te podem ajudar:

[How to connect with paired Bluetooth device programmatic in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369585/how-to-connect-with-paired-bluetooth-device-programmatic-in-android?lq=1)

[How to send file from Android device to other device through Bluetooth by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227498/how-to-send-file-from-android-device-to-other-device-through-bluetooth-by-code)

Answer (score 0):

Você deverá utilizar a API de Bluetooth do Android SDK, com o link do @PerryWerneck e esta documentação do BluetoothSocket acho que conseguirá resolver o seu problema.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html

Documentação completa da API de Bluetooth da SDK:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html

Caso queira já um código de exemplo para se orientar, segue abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274660/2132522

Comment: eu já tinha dado uma olhada.. na documentação falta algumas coisas q eles não explicam com clareza passando por cima de algumas coisas importantes.. queria realmente um codigo completo e funcional.

Comment: Qual seria exatamente a sua dúvida? O que falta para você para funcionar? Até que ponto chegou?